# How to do redirecting to another page using form in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<form method="post" action="register_enquiry.php">
```

This code is not redirecting to "register_enquiry" page. Please let me know what's wrong in this. It's giving a blank page.

Comment: check your `error.log` in your `apache` and post the error info please

Comment: on submitting form, what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is your register_enquiry page empty? Did you add a submit button?

Try this for Your initial page.

```
<form method="POST" action="register_enquiry.php">
    <input type="text" name="nameWanted">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the register_enquiry.php page.

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
    // do want ever you want
}

?>
<p>Welcome, My register_enquiry.php page</p>
```

This has worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `formaction="register_enquiry.php"` on your submit button.May be that helps